# How do I get the file offset in an ELF binary corresponding to a label outputted by objdump?

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, x86, elf

Suppose I have an ELF binary `prog` and suppose `objdump -d prog` produces output along the following lines [snippet]:

```
0000000000400601 <.cstart_c941>:
  400601:   eb 01                   jmp    400604 <.end_c941>

0000000000400603 <.cslot_c941>:
  400603:   84                      .byte 0x84

0000000000400604 <.end_c941>:
  400604:   48 81 ec 80 00 00 00    sub    $0x80,%rsp
  40060b:   50                      push   %rax
  40060c:   53                      push   %rbx
  40060d:   56                      push   %rsi
  40060e:   48 31 c0                xor    %rax,%rax
  400611:   48 c7 c6 41 06 40 00    mov    $0x400641,%rsi
```

What I need is the file offset corresponding to `.cslot_c941`, since I need to modify the byte at this position.

How would I accomplish this task?

Comment: Use the section headers (`objdump -h`) and adjust by the virtual address offset. Alternatively, just search for a sufficiently long byte sequence.

Comment: @Jester - Would you elaborate on your answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get *OBJDUMP* to dump the file offsets by using the `-F`. From the [*OBJDUMP* documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html):

> ```
> objdump 
>          ..snip..
>          [-F|--file-offsets]
>          ..snip..
> ```

Try using `objdump -DF prog`. You should see each label listed with the file offset with information like:

```
0000000000400601 <.cstart_c941>: (File Offset: 0xXXXXXXXX)
```

`0xXXXXXXXX` should be the file offset of that label.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful!